# Charging Port cover on devices - How to Improve resilience and prevent breakage?

Tags: lifespan

So a barely used set of Bluetooth headphones that I had lying in a box unused.  I got them out and moved aside the cover of charging port pushed in the USB charger and left it overnight.

Next morning the cover had broken.  (Factory/ Stock pictures attached below)

**Solution ideas?**

- Is there some material/ liquid or cream or chemical that helps keep such rubber charging port covers "flexible" and not dry and brittle causing easier breakage?

  - Some add-on/ stick-on/ latch-on to it to prevent breakage?
- Are there some methods / directional ideas that help us assess the best direction or way to move the covers?

It's evident that its a common issue. Wondering if people have developed some life hacks on the matter, around the above ideas or other ideas.

E.g.

- https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/383648-fragile-charging-port-cover.html
- https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/380144-charger-cover-broke.html

Pictures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't forget to let the manufacturer know about their shoddy materials. At the same time copy everyone via social media to "emphasize" your position. A public disclosure goes the extra distance to discourage private "We're sorry; but, …" meaningless apologies in reply.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to reduce the brittleness of the covers.

What you need to understand: Manufactures will usually make the covers with some blend of rubber, silicone or some other soft man made synthetic. After time and/or use the rubber will dry and become brittle leading to a failure.

To try and prevent this, you will can try the following.

- Reduce wear - use only when needed (this one is obvious)
- Keep it clean without using solvents (water and maybe mild soap)
- Keep it soft

  - If it comes off, stick it in some hot water for a few mintues
  - If it does not come off, spray some silicone lubricant (with no cleaners added) on a Q-Tip and give the stress areas a good coat and let it sit for a few minutes.

When removing, reducing any bending. Most will have some slack to them so when you pull it off, be sure to pull it out most of the way before bending it back.

*When it does break*, just throw it away and use a piece of Wax Ear Plug (usually in the swimming section) to cover the port and keep debris out. Doesn't look as good, but will do a really good job.